# ASP.NET Form fields are populated after jquery .ready() event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a legacy .NET WebForms application that populates several fields on the page (which are disabled input text fields). for illustration, let's say that the fields are grades for classes in school. The fields are populated dynamically.
Now let's say I want to populate another field (maybe, average grade). I was planning to do that on the client side through JQuery.

The strange thing I noticed that in JQuery's ready function the value of those fields is not populated. (I also tried $(window).load that is called later - but the same results). So, `$("#fieldid1").val()` is empty. All other values (id, innerHTML, etc.) **are** populated, so I know I am looking at the right field.

However, at some point the field gets populated with the value from the server. I see it on the screen, and if I have click() handler function I am getting the right value for the same call.

Is it WebForms behavior? Or it is something with this forms engine that does something funny. I looked in the Firebug - there are no AJAX calls after the form is loaded...

Comment: Is this Classic asp ? because most of the time with web forms your controls inherent from the parent markup that runs on the server level.  Make you are referencing a ID that hasn't been manipulated by web forms.` $('#<%= fieldid1.ClientID %>').val()` or try accessing it by its class. '$(".fieldid1Class").val()'

Comment: Check the rendered HTML and see if the ID fieldid1 exists.   Sometimes ASP.NET 'mangles' ID's to ensure they are unique.   I blogged some solutions here: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/finding-controls-in-a-master-page-with-jquery

Comment: @SteveWellens , your blog makes it much more difficult than it is. You can either set the ClientIdMode to Static for the controls you need to access on the client side (or set that property from page or web.config level) or use inline ASPX markup to embed the ID.

Comment: Felix, if you want help with your question, you should embed the relevant code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mason - ClientIdMode was not available when the blog was written.

Comment: Guys, first thank you for you eagerness to help. As I mentioned in my post, the field value *is* available on click after load - so it's not related to mangling and, obviously, fieldname exists. It is .NET WebForms and *not* classic ASP.
@mason - thank you for the link, but the code can be summed as `var x = $("#fieldid1").val()`
Given that I didn't get a substantive answer, I am now suspecting this proprietary form engine more than before. I just didn't realize that it was possible to populate the fields **after** ready() event. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the fields were withing iframe. I was putting my jquery code within the same iframe as well. However, they were indeed populated from the parent page *after* my jquery ready() code was executed. Mystery solved!